# Grant PG permissions to not existing tables

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I would like to have a dedicated user in the schema, that can have access to tables/objects by pattern like `foo*` (starts with `foo`).

He should have permissions to create new tables like `foo_table1` and perform insert/update on existing tables.

It is possible with MySQL, but not sure about PostgreSQL (easily, without stored procedures or other magic).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: In Postgres  I would grant privileges to the user to create objects in a _schema_ `foo` rather than using a name prefix. (I'm curious how do you give permissions based on a name prefix to non-existing tables in MySQL?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without claiming to address your 'by pattern' requirement, granting privileges on not-yet-extant objects is addressed by `Alter Default Privileges`

```
Create schema foo;

Grant Usage On Schema foo to foouser;

Alter Default Privileges In Schema foo 
  GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, Truncate ON TABLES To foouser;

Alter Default Privileges In Schema foo 
  Grant EXECUTE on FUNCTIONS To foouser;
```

Or simply

```
Alter Default Privileges In Schema foo GRANT All Privileges To foouser;
```

As @a_horse_with_no_name observes, the schema is the usual way to group objects for privileges. **Using schemas for security is much less error prone than using naming patterns**, so I think we should recommend you go this way anyway!

`foouser` only needs to use a dot in their statements:

```
create table foo.mine ( id int)
select * from foo.mine
```

**PS Why are name-patterns an error-prone way of doing security?**

Because you never know whether a year later you're going to

```
create table food_for_top_secret_party
```

which matches pattern `foo*`, and so can be not only read, but also accidentally `dropped`, by `foouser`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems reasonable. I'll try and return to accept the answer if this works for me.